# Filling array of a struct, that was declared in .h, inside function in .c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, header-files

Ok so I have this struct declared at my .h file:

```
typedef struct Vet32 {
    char key;
    int thrash[7];
} Vet32;
```

And I have one function in my other .c file, that is not my main.c, where I wanna fill my array thrash in one line like:

`vector[i].thrash[] = { 1, 3, 9, 123, 85, 12, 875 };`

But I always get errors from my gcc compiler when i try to fill my array like this. The function i use is:

```
void createVet(FILE* arq, Vet32 vector[22]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++ ) {
        fscanf(arq, "%c", vector[i].key);
        vector[i].thrash[7] = { 1, 3, 9, 123, 85, 12, 875 };
    }
}
```

The lenght of the arrays are always that. Anyone can help me with this? it really annoys me this smalls errors in C xD.

Comment: vector[i].thrash[7] can only hold one integer. You are trying to assign many.

Comment: @JustinJ.: Actually, `vector[i].thrash[7]` can hold zero. It's an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Change loop body to `vector[i] = (Vet32){ fgetc(arq), {1, 3, 9, 123, 85, 12, 875} };`

Comment: I only realised it now the silly mistake of thrash[7] = ..., but the problem would also persist with thrash[] = or thrash [], but thx to you guys I've fixed my program, thx very much :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a syntax for *initialization*. Initialization gives a variable its initial value, and this value has to be constant at compile time. This is an important requirement as it allows the compiler to emit the value directly, e.g. in a *data segment* in the resulting binary.

But you try to use it in an *assignment*. An assignment changes the value of a variable at runtime.

For all versions of [c](/questions/tagged/c), it is *impossible* to assign to an array. So the most straight-forward way to do what you want to achieve is to assign each individual member:

```
vector[i].thrash[0] = 1;
vector[i].thrash[1] = 3;
[...]
```

But since you use a `struct`, there is another way. A `struct` can be assigned as a whole, and this can be done from a *compound literal*, IIRC starting from [c99](/questions/tagged/c99). Here's some example code illustrating this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Vet32 {
    char key;
    int thrash[7];
} Vet32;


void initVet(Vet32 *self)
{
    *self = (Vet32) {
        .key = 0,
        .thrash = { 1, 3, 9, 123, 85, 12, 875 }
    };
}

int main(void)
{
    Vet32 vet;
    initVet(&vet);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        printf("vet[%d] = %d\n", i, vet.thrash[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The *compound literal* looks like an *initializer*, but prepended with an explicit notation of the type in parantheses, just like it was a cast.

Answer (score 2):

You can only initialize arrays when declaring them. If you want to fill them out later, you need to use a loop or something like [`memcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html):

```
void createVet(FILE* arq, Vet32 vector[22]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++ ) {
        fscanf(arq, "%c", &(vector[i].key));

        int values[7] = { 1, 3, 9, 123, 85, 12, 875 };
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++ ) {
            vector[i].thrash[j] = values[j];
        }
    }
}
```

With `memcpy`, instead of the new `for` loop I added earlier, you can do this:

```
int values[7] = { 1, 3, 9, 123, 85, 12, 875 };
memcpy(vector[i].thrash, values, sizeof(values));
```